# function - tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath not getting called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, tableview

I have this code and it never seems to be called, I've put a break point in and everything:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var cell = UITableViewCell()

cell.textLabel.text = "dlfkhasdfa"
return cell
}
```

I'm extending these classes UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and in viewDidLoad I'm doing this:

```
self.storiesTableView.dataSource = self
self.storiesTableView.delegate = self
```

The real confusion is that tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is being called so it's like something happens between those two calls and I'm just here scratching my head.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! Figured it out, in tableView:numberOfRowsInSelection the return value was zero somehow. Changing it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you have more than one section in the func numberOfSectionsInTableView() as mine was set to return zero by default.

Comment: Sorry, that should say at least one section.